# How does node.js handle skipped optional arguments

Tags: node.js, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

What happens if I skip an optional argument in node.js.
I have the following code:

```js
    //server.mjs
    import { exec } from 'child_process';
    
    var myCommand = "ver";
    
    function execute(command, callback){
        // child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])
        exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
    };
    
    function myCallback(text){
        console.log(text);
        console.log('done!');
    }
    
    execute(myCommand, myCallback);
    console.log('Start!');
```

Now from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) I know that exec has one mandatory argument (command) and two optional arguments (options and the callback).
In my example I only provided the "command" and the "callback" to the exec function but no "options".
How does node.js know that my second argument is actually the callback function and not the options object?

EDIT: As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) pointed out, it is just the exec function that checks for exactly that:

```js
function normalizeExecArgs(command, options, callback) {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options;
    options = undefined;
  }

  // Make a shallow copy so we don't clobber the user's options object.
  options = { ...options };
  options.shell = typeof options.shell === 'string' ? options.shell : true;

  return {
    file: command,
    options: options,
    callback: callback
  };
}
```

Comment: It literally just checks whether or not it's a function: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8d6b74d3474080bd29dd698f55e88aba17c6a69e/lib/child_process.js#L139-L154.

Comment: Well... I guess that is exactly what I wanted to know. Sometimes it is that easy. Thank you